# WebDialogResult YesNoCancel

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I want to ask for help, about YesNoCancel, it does not work to cancel, they only work yes and no, less cancel

[Example: here works well, when I press No](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1Y2Q.png)

When I press Cancel, you must deactivate the detraction check, as shown in this picture, but do nothing to cancel.

[Example: It does not work, when I press cancel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VRQH.png)

this is my code:

```
protected virtual void APInvoice_TBienServ_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache,PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e) 
 {

  APInvoice api = Base.Document.Current;

   XTAPInvoice apiExt = PXCache<APInvoice>.GetExtension<XTAPInvoice>(api);

       if (api.DocType == APDocType.Invoice) 
         {
              switch (this.Base.Document.Ask("", confirma, MessageButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageIcon.Warning))
                     {

                    case WebDialogResult.Yes:
                    apiExt.AutoDetraccion = true;
                    apiExt.Detraccion = false;
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<XTAPInvoice.autodetraccion>(cache, api, true);
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<XTAPInvoice.detraccion>(cache, api, false);
                    break;

                    case WebDialogResult.No:
                    apiExt.Detraccion = true;
                    apiExt.AutoDetraccion = false;
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<XTAPInvoice.detraccion>(cache, api, true);
                    PXUIFieldAttribute.SetVisible<XTAPInvoice.autodetraccion>(cache, api, false);
                    break;
                    //cancel
                    default:
                    apiExt.Detraccion = false;
                    apiExt.AutoDetraccion = false;
                    break;
            }
         }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you do more basic test cases to assess that Cancel is not working.

You could open the Help->Trace / Tools->Trace Window in Acumatica and write the result directly in traces.

Perhaps you just want to invoke default cancel behavior, for this you can set e.Cancel = true.

```
switch (answer)
{
    case WebDialogResult.Yes:
        PXTrace.WriteInformation("YES");
        break;

    case WebDialogResult.No::
        PXTrace.WriteInformation("NO");
        break;

    case WebDialogResult.Cancel:
        // Cancelling event
        e.Cancel = true;

        PXTrace.WriteInformation("CANCEL");
        break;
    default:
        PXTrace.WriteInformation("DEFAULT");
        break;
}
```